# apt install remove other softwares (not dependencies)

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, software-center, uninstall

A beginner here.

I tried to install wine by using `sudo apt install wine`. This thing has happened to me twice. I tried to install wine but it removed other software like discord, google chrome and zoom. I had to install them again. Why is this happening? I understand the `The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:` thing. But why it is removing chrome and discord? Here is the output images below - `The following packages will be REMOVED:`
[image: The following packages will be REMOVED:]

It removes all the software mentioned:
[image: It removes all the software mentioned]

I don't know why this is happening and how to stop this.

Comment: That won't happen if you install `wine` that was built for your *unstated* release of what I assume is Ubuntu, however if you use a 3rd party package, it may have *dependency* rules that clash with your installed packages and the removal is the only way the package manager can accomplish your given instruction. I would check your sources for issues (do you have any 3rd party sources (eg. PPAs) added etc; I'm betting you do unless the 3rd party packages you added were *snaps* (which don't cause conflicts)).  For specific advice please provide actual details (command & all output and not as pic)

Comment: if the dependencies are tripping you up, don't forget each dependency can have its own dependencies..... which is why commands ask for your confirmation before they actually execute  (ie. don't use `-y` unless you've done your homework & actually know the results).

Comment: @guiverc Yes, I had added PPA from the official Wine website https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu but I removed it shortly after from Software & Updates and used sudo apt install wine instead.  And yes I shouldn't have pressed y blindly ;(. Thanks though.

Comment: If you have installed any packages from the PPA whilst it was active on your system, they may have subsequently pulled in extra 3rd party packages which remained after you removed the source...  A tool `ppa-purge` exists so you can remove such events, so as to not get bit later because you forgot the packages were installed (your logs are also useful; `/var/log/apt/history.log` to see consequences of actions).. Don't forget an official wine repository isn't an official Ubuntu repository (it's 3rd party for Ubuntu).

Comment: AAh, okay, thanks a lot. Will use `ppa-purge`.